# How do you define an array of funs(functions) in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, function, kotlin

How do you define an array of funs(functions) in Kotlin?

This is my assumption of how it would be done...

```
this.funs = arrayOf : Unit(
    this::openCamera,
    this::sendSMS,
    this::makeCall
        )
```

How would I invoke each array item as a function at runtime?  Would simply specifying 'funs' in place of either openCamera(), sendSMS(), and MakeCall() in a forEach() loop work?

or.. is this the way that I would invoke each function:

```
val function = getFunction(funs)
function()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had some functions defined as

```
fun one()   { print("ONE") }
fun two()   { print("TWO") }
fun three() { print("THREE") }
```

Then you can create an array of these as

```
fun someFun(){
    val arrayOfFunctions: Array<() -> Unit> = arrayOf(::one, ::two, ::three)
    arrayOfFunctions.forEach { function ->
       function()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked...